# Scala- trying to simplify nested case pattern matching

Tags: scala

```
userResultList.headOption match {
  case Some(userResult) => userResult.user match {
    case Some(user) => Some(user)
    case _ => None
  }
  case _ => None
}
```

What's a good way to simplify this?

Comment: What is the type of `userResultList`?

Comment: It's a sequence of UserResults

Comment: Copy and paste the type from the REPL so we're not guessing.

Answer (score 4):

Your inner match on `userResult.user` looks redundant so you can simplify the outer match using `flatMap`:

```
userResultList.headOption.flatMap(_.user)
```